# New-ADServiceAccount Powershell script is not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

Hi StackOverflow family,

Hope you are well?
I’m facing one issue in the PowerShell script for the last 4 days. I have created/ modified it more than 50 times same script and tested it. every time it is going to catch or get some error. and error is not clear so can't find the cause.

can you help me here?
Thanks

```
if ($action -like 'create_ad_svc_acc') {                      
<#
 | Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $svcAccountName -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
#>

try{
    $svcAccountName = "testing_account" 
    $passwordExp = "no"
    $InteractiveLogon = "yes"               
    #password
    $password = "Welcome@1234567890"                              
    #organizational unit
    $path = "OU=Service,OU=Accounts,OU=testcompany OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=internal" #changed the path for company privacy pupose
    #Dormant OU
    $dormantPath = "OU=Users,OU=Dormant,DC=domain,DC=internal"
    #dns host (mandatory)            
    $dnsHost="test.domain.internal" #changed the host for company privacy pupose
    #Set Password expiry
    if ($passwordExp -like 'no'){                  #environment dependent
        $expiryFlag = $True
    }
    else{
        $expiryFlag = $false
    }

    #create new account

        New-ADServiceAccount `
        -SamAccountName $svcAccountName `
        -name $svcAccountName `
        -Enabled $true `
        -Path $path `
        -DNSHostName $dnsHost `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `

    sleep 2

    if (Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity $svcAccountName){
         if ( $InteractiveLogon -like "no"){
                    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GBL_DenyLogonLocally -Members $svcAccountName
         }
    }
    Write-Host "Service account has been created"
}
catch{
    Write-Warning "There was an error while creating the service account"
}

return
```

}

Comment: Can you remove the unnecessary PowerShell tags leaving only the one you're currently running? Also, what errors? Can you post them? You may want to have the error be displayed for troubleshooting purposes, so at least use `$_.Exception.Message`(or `$_`) in your catch block, or dig into `$Error` for a little more in depth look. Maybe the line number will give you a clue. Also, when using wildcard expressions, unless the string being matches is the same being evaluated against, you'll have to provide a wildcard (`*`): `"test"  -Like 'st'` <eq false. `"test" -Like '*st'` <eq true

Answer (score 0):

- As advised in comments, you can display the error by putting the default error output variable in the catch block
- When you create an account and want to check it quickly you must query the **same** domain controller as the one you created it on, else the script can error because it checked another DC but it hadnt yet replicated to that DC

  ```
    if ($action -like 'create_ad_svc_acc') {                      
    <#
     | Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $svcAccountName -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force)
    #>

    try{
        $svcAccountName = "testing_account" 
        $passwordExp = "no"
        $InteractiveLogon = "yes"               
    #password
        $password = "Welcome@1234567890"                              
    #organizational unit
        $path = "OU=Service,OU=Accounts,OU=testcompany OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=internal" #changed the path for company privacy pupose
    #Dormant OU
        $dormantPath = "OU=Users,OU=Dormant,DC=domain,DC=internal"
    #dns host (mandatory)            
        $dnsHost="test.domain.internal" #changed the host for company privacy pupose

    #Set Password expiry
        if ($passwordExp -like 'no'){                  #environment dependent
            $expiryFlag = $True
        }
        else{
            $expiryFlag = $false
        }

    #create new account

        New-ADServiceAccount `
        -SamAccountName $svcAccountName `
        -name $svcAccountName `
        -Enabled $true `
        -Path $path `
        -DNSHostName $dnsHost `
        -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) `

        sleep 2
        ### Query the SAME DC we created the account on
        if (Get-ADServiceAccount -Identity $svcAccountName -Server $DNSHostname -ErrorAction Stop){
            Write-Host "Service account has been created"
            if ( $InteractiveLogon -like "no"){
                Add-ADGroupMember -Identity GBL_DenyLogonLocally -Members $svcAccountName
            }
        }
        ###
    }
    catch{
        Write-Warning "There was an error while creating the service account"
    ### This var contains the error
    $_
    ###
    }
    return
    }
  ```